# Is there an easy way to paste rich text into posts?

Tags: feature-request, edits, markdown

I frequently find myself trying to paste a quotation that contains some rich text, such as italics or links, and I have to reapply all the formatting myself.

It would be great if there were a way to paste rich text and have any formatting and links carry over automatically.

Comment: I believe this works in the Stacks Editor (which currently appears as an opt-in test on MSE and MSO, and as the default editor in a few other spots – such as Staging Ground on SO and election pages network-wide), at least if you're pasting the text while you're in the rich-text mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I link to a page (e.g., documentation), and provide a quote with the specific information I'm highlighting.

If the quoted source uses tidy HTML, often one can copy that and mix it with Markdown. [Like](http://imranontech.com/2007/02/20/did-bill-gates-say-the-640k-line/):

> **“640K ought to be enough for anybody.” -Bill Gates (1981)**
>
> One of the most quoted lines of the computer era.  Certainly the most quoted line attributed to the Microsoft founder.
>
> However it is only “attributed” as in 1996 Bill decided to publically deny it in an interview:
>
> > **INTERVIEWER** I read in a newspaper that in 1981 you said, “640K of memory should be enough for anybody.” What did you mean when you said this?
>
> > **BILL GATES**: I’ve said some stupid things and some wrong things, but not that. No one involved in computers would ever say that a certain amount of memory is enough for all time.
> > (…)
> > We at Microsoft disagreed. We knew that even 16-bit computers, which had 640K  of available address space, would be adequate for only four or five years.

(View [the source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/001b5f90-d827-4058-9899-b7ecb0a9b998/view-source) of this post.)

Comment: Is "tidy HTML" supposed to be related to http://tidy.sourceforge.net, or just a description?

Comment: "tidy" means unbloated semantic HTML that uses [supported tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/998878)

Answer (score 15):

I can't see this being implemented.

Why are you posting so much *preformatted* text? If it's copied from another site then you are  risking copyright infringement claims.

When answering on Stack Exchange you should be summarising and expanding on what already exists. Linking to relevant pages - but including the salient points in the answer. This ensures that subsequent visitors don't have to go trawling the internet following one link after another and that, should a site go dark, the information is still available **here**.

Comment: Not to mention the issues surrounding technical feasibility.

Comment: That's exactly the reason I would be posting a quote in the first place. I link to a page (e.g., documentation), and provide a quote with the specific information I'm highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a good answer for [ChrisF's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102350/pasting-rich-text/102351#102351) you might be interested in various third-party converters:

- [PanDoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) (link goes to a online live trial)
- [Markdownify](http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/) is a PHP tool for converting HTML to Markdown.

Comment: *Markdownify* is now on [github](https://github.com/Elephant418/Markdownify).