# What is the quickest way to copy/paste text without losing formatting?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to paste rich text into posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102350/is-there-an-easy-way-to-paste-rich-text-into-posts)

So if I want to copy/paste the bulleted lines from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables#Derivatives_of_action,

I get this...

> The energy of a particle at a certain event is the negative of the
>   derivative of the action along a trajectory of that particle ending at
>   that event with respect to the time of the event. The linear momentum
>   of a particle is the derivative of its action with respect to its
>   position. The angular momentum of a particle is the derivative of its
>   action with respect to its angle (angular position). The electric
>   potential (φ, voltage) at an event is the negative of the derivative
>   of the action of the electromagnetic field with respect to the density
>   of (free) electric charge at that event. The magnetic potential (A) at
>   an event is the derivative of the action of the electromagnetic field
>   with respect to the density of (free) electric current at that event.
>   The electric field (E) at an event is the derivative of the action of
>   the electromagnetic field with respect to the electric polarization
>   density at that event. The magnetic induction (B) at an event is the
>   derivative of the action of the electromagnetic field with respect to
>   the magnetization at that event. The Newtonian gravitational potential
>   at an event is the negative of the derivative of the action of the
>   Newtonian gravitation field with respect to the mass density at that
>   event.

It ain't pretty at all. Now - while I can try to manually change the formatting of the paste (so that it can have bulleted points), it can be pretty time-consuming after a while. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: You could copy the wikimarkup, but the wiki links won't transfer. I think the fastest way is still to add `*` in front of the newlines

Answer (score 6):

Not really, the Stack Exchange engine only recognizes Markdown as far as I know. So unless you can find an automatic wiki-to-markdown converter (for which you might try asking on [Webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)?) there's no shortcut to manually converting it.

One thing that might make the process a little easier is to click on the "edit" link on the Wikipedia page and copy the source markup, rather than just copying the rendered HTML.

Comment: @InquilineKea - That is exactly it. What is being copied in/out of the clipboard is not html and text, it is basic formatting and text, something that SE sites have not been designed to translate it's formatting mechanism (markdown).