# What's the best way to quote Wikipedia in SE?

Tags: support, markdown, wikipedia

Ideally I'd like to have SE recreate the formatting in Wikipedia, with footnotes and all. Any way of doing this, either by copying the source markdown, or — even better! — the RTF directly from the screen?

For instance, let's say there's a question about democracy (in a particular circumstance, or in general), and we'd like quote the Wikipedia definition. How do we change this:

```
'''Democracy''' ({{lang-gr|δημοκρατία}} ''{{lang|grc|dēmokraa thetía}}'', literally "rule by people"), in modern usage, has three senses all for a system of government where the citizens exercise power by [[Vote|voting]]. In a [[direct democracy]], the citizens as a whole form a governing body, and vote directly on each issue, e.g. on the passage of a particular tax law. In a [[representative democracy]] the citizens elect representatives from among themselves. These representative meet to form a governing body, such as a [[legislature]]. In a [[constitutional democracy]] the powers of the majority are exercised within the framework of a representative democracy, but the constitution limits the majority and protects the minority, usually through the enjoyment by all of certain individual rights, e.g. freedom of speech, or freedom of association.<ref>[[Oxford English Dictionary]]: ''Democracy''.</ref><ref name="britannica">{{cite book |last1=Watkins |first1=Frederick |authorlink1=Democracy |title=Encyclopædia Britannica |date=1970 |publisher=William Benton |isbn=0-85229-135-3 |pages=215-223 |edition=Expo '70 |language=English |format=Hardcover|volume=7|}}</ref> Democracy is sometimes referred to as "rule of the majority".<ref>{{cite web|url=http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/democracy|title=Democracy – Definition of Democracy by Merriam-Webster|publisher=}}</ref> Democracy is a system of processing conflicts in which outcomes depend on what participants do, but no single force controls what occurs and its outcomes.
```

… or — even better! — that:

[image]

… into that:

> **Democracy** ([Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_language): δημοκρατία *dēmokraa thetía*, literally "rule by people"), in modern usage, has three senses all for a system of government where the citizens exercise power by [voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vote). In a [direct democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_democracy), the citizens as a whole form a governing body, and vote directly on each issue, e.g. on the passage of a particular tax law. In a [representative democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representative_democracy) the citizens elect representatives from among themselves. These representative meet to form a governing body, such as a [legislature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legislature). In a [constitutional democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_democracy) the powers of the majority are exercised within the framework of a representative democracy, but the constitution limits the majority and protects the minority, usually through the enjoyment by all of
>   certain individual rights, e.g. freedom of speech, or freedom of association.<sup>1 2</sup> Democracy is sometimes referred to as "rule of the majority".<sup>3</sup> Democracy is a system of processing conflicts in which
>   outcomes depend on what participants do, but no single force controls
>   what occurs and its outcomes.
>
> <sub>1. [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary): *Democracy*.</sub>
>
> <sub>2. Watkins, Frederick (1970). *Encyclopædia Britannica* (Hardcover). **7** (Expo '70 ed.). William Benton. pp. 215–223. ISBN [0-85229-135-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-85229-135-3).</sub>
>
> <sub>3. ["Democracy – Definition of Democracy by Merriam-Webster"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/democracy).</sub>

Comment: Very related, maybe dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102350/is-there-an-easy-way-to-paste-rich-text-into-posts

Comment: Very related indeed, @shadow-wizard, but not the same.

Answer (score 3):

[This technique<sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes) will enable footnote style formatting in your posts on SE.

When attempting to recreate RTF/Wikipedia styling, I kindly remind you to consider whether you want to ***create a Wikipedia style article in SE...*** or rather simply ***quote a tiny snippet*** of something. I'd discourage the former, and encourage the latter.

<sub>*1. This is an example of the technique I've linked to up above. Ah, the joys of markdown.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, great. Now, how about being able to do that automatically, without having to change all formatting markup tags manually?

Comment: @AndréLevy Please give a concrete example. If you are quoting from Wikipedia for example, it should be a matter of a couple copy-and-pastes, where automation would give minimal benefit. Something like [Markdown It](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) comes to mind, but it may be much more than what you need/want.

Comment: Markdown It is for rendering markdown onto html, no? This is more of a [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) job. So my question is about how to parametrize pandoc — or another similar tool — to produce the effect you suggested. I've just added an example to main question, using your suggested formatting.